# Delete elements of a Dataframe if they are in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, compare

I am asking you help for a part of my Python script I am struggling with:
I have a dataframe with 4 columns :

```
           keyword  impressions  clicks   ctr
0            About          1.0     0.0    0.000000
1            Achat         12.0     2.0    16.6666667
2           Action          1.0     0.0    0.000000
3            Adele         14.0     1.0    7.14285714
```

this dataframe contains thousands of lines. I am trying to delete lines from this dataframe if it's 'keyword' is in a list (for ex: list =  {'Action', 'About}

Here is the code line I made :

```
df.drop( df[ df['keyword'] in list ].index, inplace=True)
```

but I get this error :

```
File "/Users/adamn/Desktop/test_lambda.py", line 87, in <module>
 df.drop( df[ df['keyword'] in exc ].index, inplace=True)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site- 
 packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1785, in __hash__
raise TypeError(
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I do not really understand what it stands for ...

How can I resolve it ?or how should I process to get the result I want ?

Thank's for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want!

```
df.drop( df[ df['keyword'].apply(lambda x: x in list) ].index, inplace=True)
```

#### Why does it work?

You were checking whether the series `df['keyword']` was in list `list`. What you had to do was to check if the element `x` in the series `df['keyword']` was in list `list`. So, we use the `apply` function which "applies" a given function to every element in a `pandas Series` or `DataFrame`.

#### What are lambdas?

Lambdas are like inline functions in `C`. An equivalent code of this using functions would be:

```
def func(x):
    return x in list

df.drop( df[ df['keyword'].apply(func)].index, inplace=True)
```

PS: I would suggest not to use 'list' as a variable name as it is a datatype in python.

Comment: Yes, this is excactly what I wanted, but I'm not very familiar with lambdas in pandas so I didn't think about it. And yes, my list has a different name, I just named it 'list' here so it was easier to understand. Thank you very much for you help !

Answer (score 0):

Using `boolean indexing` is far more efficient than using `apply`.

```
df = df.loc[~df.keyword.isin(['About', 'Action'])]
```

NOTE: reset the index if required.

```
df = df.loc[~df.keyword.isin(['About', 'Action'])].reset_index()
```

Documentation link -> [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) / [indexing/selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)